# Cannot access history number variable HISTCMD from within PROMPT_COMMAND script

Tags: bash, command-prompt

In all versions of bash that I tried (3, 4, 5) I cannot access the command history number (special variable `HISTCMD`) in the context of running `PROMPT_COMMAND`. Quite oddly, it evaluates to `1` every time.

```
bash-5.0$ echo $BASH_VERSION
5.0.11(1)-release

# Set up the prompting. Takes effect immediately.
bash-5.0$ PROMPT_COMMAND='echo In PROMPT_COMMAND. PID: ${$} HISTCMD: ${HISTCMD}'
In PROMPT_COMMAND. PID: 96047 HISTCMD: 1

# Interactively we can get the variable, but right after, when PROMPT_COMMAND runs, nope
bash-5.0$ echo Interactively: PID: ${$} HISTCMD: ${HISTCMD}
Interactively: PID: 96047 HISTCMD: 67
In PROMPT_COMMAND. PID: 96047 HISTCMD: 1

# Meanwhile it continues to increment interactively. PROMPT_COMMAND is not in a forked subprocess.
bash-5.0$ echo Interactively: PID: ${$} HISTCMD: ${HISTCMD}
Interactively: PID: 96047 HISTCMD: 68
In PROMPT_COMMAND. PID: 96047 HISTCMD: 1
```

It's not like PROMPT_COMMAND is insulated from metavariables. `$_` works just fine for example. It also does not seem possible to leverage the `PSn` prompt format specifier `\#`.

Comment: I just ran into the same issue myself; you may want to report it as a bash bug.  I doubt, however, that that will help, because it's likely that what's happening is that history is swapped out/disabled while PROMPT_COMMAND is running, and that it's necessary for it to do so for PROMPT_COMMAND to work correctly in some other way.  But reporting it is still a good idea.

Comment: This appears to be fixed in bash 5.1. I am using HISTCMD in my PROMPT_COMMAND and it works in 5.1.x, but not on my older machine running 4.4.x.